# Writing stm32 ADC values to SD card

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery, adc

I can't read uint data(in text file) from sdcard which has been written from stm32 adc. I am able to write data to sd card but weird symbols appear when I open txt file in my latop.

I am using SDIO and FATFS

Comment: My crystal ball tells me the error is on line 42 in your code.

Comment: So basically you are saying that you managed to sample analog values using the ADC and got the SDIO peripheral working with FATFS (granted, mostly for free thanks to CubeMx), but failed to convert your hex values to ascii before writing them to SD card?

Comment: @HenkKok exactly.

Comment: Thank you guys for commenting, I already solved it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(f_mount(&myFAT,SD_Path, 1)==FR_OK)
    {   
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14);
        f_open(&myFile, "test1.txt\0",FA_WRITE|FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
        for(int i=0; i<1000;i++){
        sprintf(msg,"%hu\r\n",data[i]);
        f_write(&myFile,msg,10,&byteCount);
        }
        f_close(&myFile);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15);
    }
```

Comment: I just created a buffer with the size 1000 to write my ADC values and in a for loop converted it to char and then wrote to SDcard. For me, it is working properly.